# Data Validation if cells contain value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following piece of code in Google Apps Scripts to get get data from google spreadsheets.

```
var range1=sheet.getRange("A1:A25").getValues();
```

I want to set a criteria such that .getValues returns values only if the row contains data , for e.g. if data is present only from A1:A10, then only values from first 10 rows should be returned instead of all 25 rows. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

try:

1. Define data
2. Filter it

Sample code:

```
function GetMyRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range1=sheet.getRange("A1:A25").getValues();
  var range1notNull = notEmpty(range1);

  Logger.log(range1notNull);
}


function notEmpty(dataIn) {
  var dataOut = dataIn.filter(function(item) {
     return (item != '');
  });
  return dataOut;
}
```

I've found many useful [code from here](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2015/05/04/functional-programming-in-javascript-map-filter-reduce/)